# (Tao Analysis I Exercise 3.4.2. iii) Review my proof that $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}\left(f\left(f^{-1}\left({U}\right)\right)\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Please review my work below and let me know if there any mistakes or issues.

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a function and let $U\subseteq Y$.

Proposition: $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}\left(f\left(f^{-1}\left({U}\right)\right)\right)$.

Proof: First, note the following three equalities from the definitions of forward and inverse images of sets under the map $f$:

$$f^{-1}(U)=\{x' \in X : f(x')\in U\}$$

$$f\left(f^{-1}(U)\right)=\{f(x') : x'\in f^{-1}(U)\}$$

$$f^{-1}\left(f\left(f^{-1}(U)\right)\right)=\{x'\in X : f(x')\in f\left(f^{-1}(U)\right) \}$$

To show that $f^{-1}\left(f\left(f^{-1}(U)\right)\right)\subseteq f^{-1}(U)$, let $x \in f^{-1}\left(f\left(f^{-1}(U)\right)\right)$. This implies that $x \in X$ and $f(x)\in f\left(f^{-1}(U)\right)$, which further implies that
$f(x)=f(x')$ for some $x'\in f^{-1}(U)$. It follows that $x'\in X$ and $f(x')\in U$. Since $f(x)=f(x')$, $f(x)\in U$ and therefore $x\in f^{-1}(U)$ as desired.

To show that $f^{-1}(U)\subseteq f^{-1}\left(f\left(f^{-1}(U)\right)\right)$, let $x\in f^{-1}(U)$. It immediately follows that $f(x)\in f\left(f^{-1}(U) \right)$. Since $f^{-1}(U) \subseteq X$, it follows that $x\in X$. These two facts combined imply that $x \in f^{-1}\left(f\left(f^{-1}(U)\right)\right)$ as desired.

Note that the penultimate operation relied on the general fact that
$x\in S\subseteq X \rightarrow f(x)\in f(S)$, so you can "apply the function $f$" to the expression $x\in S$. In this particular case, $S=f^{-1}(U)$.

Likewise, the ultimate step relied on the fact that $f(x)\in U'$ if and only if $x\in f^{-1}(U')$ for any $U' \subseteq Y$. In this particular case, $U'=f\left(f^{-1}(U)\right)$

Answer (score 1):

The second part is a bit shaky (but correct). $x\in X$ needs no proof, since $X$ is the domain. Alternatively, show that $U \subseteq f(f^{-1}(U))$ and combine with
$$ U\subseteq V \Rightarrow f^{-1}(U) \subseteq f^{-1}(V). $$

The first part seems fine but again it is redundant to say an element of $X$ is an element of $X$.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I mentioned that $x\in X$ because the proof relied on known expressions fitting the mold of the set builder notation, which are specifically required to be subsets of $X$. To justify the two steps in the last part better, I can note that generally, $x \in S$ implies $f(x)\in f(S)$ and $f(x)\in U $ if and only if $x\in f^{-1}(U)$. Both of these generalities are discussed in Tao's Analysis I.

Comment: I edited my post with a bit more explanation of the last two steps. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $f^{-1}(U)=\{x\in X \,:f(x)\in U\}$, now consider $x\in f^{-1}(U)$:
$$x\in f^{-1}(U) \iff f(x) \in f(f^{-1}(U))\iff x\in f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(U))) $$

Answer (score 0):

I might get told off again for this, but...

View $\mathscr{P}(X)$ and $\mathscr{P}(Y)$ as posetal categories, ordered by $U\preceq V$ if  $U\subseteq V$. $f$ and $f^{-1}$ form functors $L:\mathscr{P}(X)\leftrightarrows\mathscr{P}(Y):R$ because if $U\subseteq V$ it's obvious that $f(U)\subseteq f(V)$ and $f^{-1}(U)\subseteq f^{-1}(V)$.

Also, $f(U)\subseteq V\iff U\subseteq f^{-1}(V)$. So, $L\dashv R$ is a Galois connection. It's then true that $LRL=L$ and $RLR=R$. In other words, $f(f^{-1}f(U)))=U$ is always true and $f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(V)))=V$.

---

I will 'concretise' this proof in less abstract terms. For $U\subseteq Y$, define $V:=f^{-1}(U)$.

- Because $f(V)\subseteq f(V)$ I get to deduce $V\subseteq f^{-1}(f(V))$.
- Because $V\subseteq V=f^{-1}(U)$, I get to deduce that $f(V)\subseteq U$.
- Because $f(V)\subseteq U$, I get to deduce that $f^{-1}(f(V))\subseteq f^{-1}(U)=V$.
- Because $f^{-1}(f(V))\subseteq V$ and $V\subseteq f^{-1}(f(V))$, I get to deduce that $V=f^{-1}(f(V))$, as desired.

Comment: I'll be able to comment in 5-10 years, depending on what direction I take my self study endeavors =D

Comment: @Dr.Momo ; ) It's just a bit of fun. I like to point out "general" or "categorical" perspectives wherever possible. If you ever do want to learn some category theory, I highly recommend Leinster's "[basic category theory](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375)" as a first introduction

Comment: @Dr.Momo I added a concrete version of this proof